# session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent

Tags: php, cookies

I am getting this header already sent error which is really disturbing me.

First, I must say most will talk about prior output before session_start but that is not what I am seeing in the file.

To clear doubts in my includes, I have reduced my code to the following but I still get the error:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   // include_once (__DIR__.'/../includes/main.php');
?>
```

I initially thought it was the include so I commented out the include and the only call is the session_start(). However, I still get the error.

One strange thing I have realised is that when I use GET method, there is no error. However, when I use POST method, I get this error.

Reading from other posts, some suggest checking for possible BOM preceding the file contents. When I viewed in hex format, this is what I saw:

```
3C 3F 70 68 70 20 0A 73 65 73 73 69 6F 6E 5F 73   <?php  .session_start(); .// include_once ...
```

I don't find any preceding Byte Order Mark. Additionally, I don't really get it why the error is generated for POST method but works with GET method. Really need help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure there's no whitespace after the closing `?>` as well (or better yet remove it completely - it's not required)

Comment: Well I found out that the request was returning the following warning:


    `Deprecated: Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated`

So headers were sent as part of the warning. I was able to solve it. Thanks.